# Derivation of specific helmholtz function relationship for an ideal gas

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

The question is to prove the following form of helmholtz function for an ideal gas

$$f=C_v (T-T_0)-C_vT \ln \frac{T}{T_0} -RT \ln \frac{V}{V_0} -s_0(T-T_0) +f_0$$

I tried using $$df=du-Tds-sdT$$
Now $du=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}dT +\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}dv$ we know $C_v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}$ and from $du=Tds-Pdv$ we get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}=T\frac{\partial s}{\partial v}_T-P$ which from Maxwell relationship is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}=T\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}_v-P$

I am unable to proceed after this.Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The derivative function is expanded from $A = U - TS $.

$$ dA = dU - T_odS - S_odT $$

For an ideal gas, $dU$ depends only on temperature $ dU = C_V dT $. Expand entropy change at constant volume $dS_V = \delta q_V / T = C_V dT / T$. Assume $C_V$ is constant. The final expression can be derived from this point.

The answer has a mistake in using $T$ rather than $T_o$.

Comment: Hi - we don't usually give away the complete solution to questions which are pretty obviously homework questions.

Comment: Absent that we do not have a requirement for designating a question as homework, the designation is subjective. What is "pretty obvious" is, the OP had a clear question and showed effort to resolve it. In any case, I've removed the (partially) complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and spotting the mistake.there is  a small typo.$ds=C_v/T dT+( \frac{\partial P}{\partial T})_vdv$